# How to retrieve Google Analytics account owner email address using API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm accessing the Google Analytics API v3.0 with the [.NET client adapter](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/).

This is all working very good, but I'd like to get the account owner e-mail address for a given account that I have access to.

The [resource description](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts) only has Id, Name, create- and update date.

Is there a way to get more detailed data for this account? Ideally the owner e-mail address or user data would be great. I couldn't find anything in the Analytics API docs, also nothing declaring that this information is NOT possible to get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics account doesn't really have an "owner" per se. Each account can have multiple users with different permissions.

Recently, Google Analytics launched a new permissions model (see this [blogpost](http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/03/11/managing-google-analytics-user-permissions/) for more info), and it'll be rolled out to all the users in the coming weeks. Currently, this information is not available though the Analytics API, but feel free to file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Good info, thanks. I see that this is a feature request since 2009... still status=new :) So I have no high hopes that Google will allow API access to user data anytime soon.